# what's the difference between "What if you stepped into" and "What if you could step into"?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

what's the difference between "*What if you stepped into*" and "*What if you could step into*"?

For example,

> “**What if you could step into** situations where political, social, and environmental issues have gotten people stuck?”

> “**What if you stepped into** situations where political, social, and environmental issues have gotten people stuck?”

Answer (score 1):

In practice there's often little difference. But consider *What if you could step into situations...? Would you?* which makes the question about the possibility and whether the reader would do anything with that possibility. The second version aims the possibility (even if just for the purposes of the question) and asks about the consequences.